# Firebase iOS com.apple.avfoundation.playerlayer.configuration crash?

Tags: ios, firebase, crashlytics

i am receiving  a crash on firebase crashlytics for iOS , and i am not able to track it , crash in :

```
Crashed: com.apple.avfoundation.playerlayer.configuration
EXC_BREAKPOINT 0x00000001028fcd3c
```

its happened on iOS 11.4+

[image]

any idea how to solve it ?

and if i have to use breakpoint in xCode can i catch it ?

i am still new in swift any advice appreciated

Comment: See [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/50453223/1200262)

Comment: @Kerberos how to implement KVO Player ?