# NSKeyValueObservation: Cannot remove an observer for the key path from object because it is not registered as an observer

Tags: ios, swift, key-value-observing, avplayerlayer

I get random crashes (which I can't reproduce on devices I own) in my app with exception:

> Cannot remove an observer Foundation.NSKeyValueObservation 0xaddress for the key path "readyForDisplay" from AVPlayerLayer 0xaddress because it is not registered as an observer.

This happens when I deallocate a UIView which contains AVPlayerLayer.

My init:

```
private var playerLayer : AVPlayerLayer { return self.layer as! AVPlayerLayer }

init(withURL url : URL) {
    ...
    self.asset = AVURLAsset(url: url)
    self.playerItem = AVPlayerItem(asset: self.asset)
    self.avPlayer = AVPlayer(playerItem: self.playerItem)
    super.init(frame: .zero)
    ...
    let avPlayerLayerIsReadyForDisplayObs = self.playerLayer.observe(\AVPlayerLayer.isReadyForDisplay, options: [.new]) { [weak self] (plLayer, change) in ... }
    self.kvoPlayerObservers = [..., avPlayerLayerIsReadyForDisplayObs, ...]
    ...
    }
```

My deinit where exception is thrown:

```
deinit {
    self.kvoPlayerObservers.forEach { $0.invalidate() }
    ...
    NotificationCenter.default.removeObserver(self)
}
```

According to Crashlytics it happens on iOS 11.4.1 on different iPhones.

The code leading to `deinit` is pretty simple:

```
// Some UIViewController context.
self.viewWithAVLayer?.removeFromSuperview()
self.viewWithAVLayer = nil
```

I would appreciate any thoughts on why this happens.

I have seen [this bug](https://bugs.swift.org/browse/SR-5816) but it doesn't seem to be the cause for me.

EDIT 1:

Additional info for posterity. On iOS 10 if I don't invalidate I get reproducible crash on deinit. On iOS 11 it works without invalidation (not checked yet if crash disappears if I don't invalidate and let observers to be `deinit`ed with my class).

EDIT 2:

Additional info for posterity: I have also found this Swift bug which might be related - [SR-6795](https://bugs.swift.org/browse/SR-6795).

Comment: Register and unregister in the main thread. And remove the observation from the array once you're done (Array.removeAll should work).

Comment: @PranavKasetti I register only in `init(withURL:` and unregister only in `deinit`. I assume that it happens on main thread since it is a UIView subclass and I don't touch it in other threads. This also means that if I created view not thru `init(withURL:` there would be no observers to invalidate.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

After

```
self.kvoPlayerObservers.forEach { $0.invalidate() }
```

Add

```
self.kvoPlayerObservers.removeAll()
```

Also I don’t like this line:

```
self.kvoPlayerObservers = [..., avPlayerLayerIsReadyForDisplayObs, ...]
```

`kvoPlayerObservers` should be a Set and you should insert observers one by one as you receive them.

Comment: Thanks for checking this question. I'll try this solution.

I have thought that since it happens in `deinit` I don't have to explicitly remove them.

Also what difference does it make to add them immediately or a couple of lines later? I agree that Set might be a better container for them than Array but I don't see why it would crash with Array in this particular case.

Comment: I don’t know if it will solve anything, so if not, we can investigate further.

Comment: Unfortunately that is the worst part of it, I can only check if it works by releasing the new app version, since I can't reproduce it on devices I have. Will keep you posted though.

Comment: Have you checked that `deinit` is actually being called? Also, is there a possibility of a threading issue?

Comment: Yes, `deinit` is definitely called, as I have added in my edit. I will double check threading issues, but there should be none since I tried to be very careful with dispatching all UI work to main thread.

Comment: All UI work, maybe, but what about observer management and whatever causes this view controller's deinit to be called? Whenever users get a bug but you don't, you should worry about threads...

Comment: I don't understand how you can meaningfully set a bounty when you have no way of knowing whether an answer is helpful or not (because you can't reproduce the issue to begin with).

Comment: Well, I think after a couple of weeks in production without crashes related to that place I can confirm that your answer was helpful. I will add my own answer with detailed description of what I did if someone is interested.

Answer (score 0):

I have accepted **matt**'s answer but I want to provide more info on how I actually tackled my problem.

My deinit that doesn't crash looks like this:

```
if let exception = tryBlock({ // tryBlock is Obj-C exception catcher.
        self.kvoPlayerObservers.forEach { $0.invalidate() };
        self.kvoPlayerObservers.removeAll()
}) {
    remoteLoggingSolution.write(exception.description)
}
... // do other unrelated stuff
```

Basically I try to catch Obj-C exception if it occurs and try to log it remotely.

I have this code in production for past 2 weeks and since then I didn't receive neither crashes nor exception logs so I assume **matt**'s proposal to add `kvoPlayerObservers.removeAll()` was correct (at least for my particular case).